# WCF method call from browser returns 400 bad request

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am using ASP.NET 3.5 with C# in visual studio 2008. 
I am naive to WCF. I have created a sample wcf application and just run it on asp.net development server in visual studio. I am calling the GetData() method i.e. auto-generated while creating applicaiton and getting 400 bad request. I have tried a lot but result is frustrating.

My Interface **IService1.cs** is as below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;

namespace WcfService1
{
    // NOTE: If you change the interface name "IService1" here, you must also update the reference to "IService1" in Web.config.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,Method="GET",UriTemplate="/getdata/{}")]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }


    // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

And Class **Service1.svc.cs** file is as below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace WcfService1
{
    // NOTE: If you change the class name "Service1" here, you must also update the reference to "Service1" in Web.config and in the associated .svc file.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }
    }
}
```

And web.config is as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                    <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
                    <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                </sectionGroup>
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings/>
    <system.web>
        <!--
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
        -->
        <compilation debug="true">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
        <authentication mode="None"/>
        <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
        <pages>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
            </compiler>
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <system.web.extensions>
        <scripting>
            <webServices>
                <!--
              Uncomment this section to enable the authentication service. Include 
              requireSSL="true" if appropriate.

          <authenticationService enabled="true" requireSSL = "true|false"/>
          -->
                <!--
              Uncomment these lines to enable the profile service, and to choose the 
              profile properties that can be retrieved and modified in ASP.NET AJAX 
              applications.

          <profileService enabled="true"
                          readAccessProperties="propertyname1,propertyname2"
                          writeAccessProperties="propertyname1,propertyname2" />
          -->
                <!--
              Uncomment this section to enable the role service.

          <roleService enabled="true"/>
          -->
            </webServices>
            <!--
        <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="true" enableCaching="true" />
        -->
        </scripting>
    </system.web.extensions>
    <!--
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="WcfService1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WcfService1.Service1Behavior">
                <!-- Service Endpoints -->
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1">
                    <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost"/>
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="WcfService1.Service1Behavior">
                    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The URL is as below :

```
http://localhost:51671/Service1.svc/getdata/1
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you just plug the URL into a browser does it tell you the service is running?

Comment: I don't know. I have a web application in which there is a wcf service. And I can run it using URL. But however, I can not for this auto-generated application.

Comment: how you are hosting the web service are you running it through visual studio or through IIS

Comment: If its a REST service shouldnt you be using the "webHttpBinding" and add a behaviour configuration of webhttp, for example: 
<endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="WcfService1.IService1">

<endpointBehaviors>
  <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp />
  </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are 4 things wrong:

First, you should be using `webHttpBinding` instead of `wsHttpBinding`. `wsHttpBinding` is for SOAP services only - not REST services.

Second, you need to add an endpoint behaviour.

So, your endpoint will look like this:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior">
```

And in the behaviors section you should have

```
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

Third, your URI template should be

```
UriTemplate="/getdata/{value}"
```

Rather than

```
UriTemplate="/getdata/{}"
```

And finally, the parameters you use in the URI template must be of type `string`, so

```
string GetData(string value);
```

rather than

```
string GetData(int value);
```

Inside your service operation you will have to parse the string value into the correct type.

Overall, it is **MUCH** easier to do REST with ASP.Net WebAPI rather than WCF REST. If you can move to .Net 4 instead of 3.5 you will make much quicker progress and you will be working with a properly supported platform.

Also, for development you should set

```
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
```

So you can get more information on what goes wrong. Remember to set it back to `false` for production though.

Comment: Thanks.. It worked. :) One more thing I want to know is, How do I know whether the service of type REST or SOAP?

Comment: @Dev: As the service author, you control whether it is REST or SOAP. In WCF, if you use webHttpBinding then it is REST. All the other binding types are SOAP. The differences between the SOAP ones are the transports (HTTP or TCP) and some other behviours like duplex, queue decoupling, support for advanced SOAP exensions etc..

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, I'm not entirely sure why, but when I removed the 'Factory' attribute to my .SVC file (you need to explicitly drag it to Visual Studio), I get my WSDL back.

I removed **Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"** so my .SVC file went from this:

`<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="ServiceNameSpace.ServiceName" CodeBehind="ServiceName.svc.cs" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>`

to this:

`<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="ServiceNameSpace.ServiceName" CodeBehind="ServiceName.svc.cs" %>`